# Decidability of PDA

Tags: turing-machines, context-free, pushdown-automata

I have following problem:

```
   INFPDA={⟨A⟩ |A is PDA and L(A)=infinite language}
```

Prove that this is decidable problem.

So my idea how to solve this problem is the following:

1. k = number of states of A, create finite automata D, which accepts all words which have length=k and more
2. Create context-free grammar G based on A

And now I am lost. If the automata would be DFA then I would do:
L(M) =L(A)∩L(D) then I would check whether L(M) = ∅ using turing machine (tm) for emptiness. And I would use pumping lemma. But as far as I know, I cannot use ∩ with context-free language.

How to prove this then, please?
Thank you

Comment: Using the pumping lemma, you should be able to show that the language generated by a context-free grammar is infinite iff it generates some word of a particular length (depending on the number of nonterminals and the length of the longest production).

Comment: Please state the problem clearly. Is the problem to determine whether L(A) is infinite? Then say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a context-free grammar $\mathcal{G}$ for $L(A)$ in [Greibach normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach_normal_form) with no useless nonterminals (i.e., non-terminals that cannot be transformed into a sequence of only terminals by applying production rules). Such a grammar can be mechanically constructed from $A$.
Now build a directed graph $G = (V,E)$ as follows:

- Each nonterminal of $\mathcal{G}$ is a vertex of $G$.
- For each production of $\mathcal{G}$ where a nonterminal $A$ appears on the left side and a (not necessarily distinct) nonterminal $B$ appears on the right side, add the edge $(A,B)$ to $G$.

Clearly if there is a cycle in $G$ then the cardinality of $L(\mathcal{G}) = L(A)$ is infinite. Indeed, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a walk from $S$ on $G$ of length $k$. By first applying the productions corresponding to the edges of this walk, and then a suitable set of productions to get rid of the leftover nonterminals, you can build a word $w \in L(A)$ such that $|w| \ge k$.

Conversely, if the language is infinite, for every $k >0$ there must be a derivation in $\mathcal{G}$ that uses at least $k \ge |V|$ productions. This induces a walk (from $S$) on $G$ of the same length $k$. This walk traverses at least $k+1 \ge |V|+1$ (not necessarily distinct) vertices of $G$ and, by the pigeonhole principle, at least one vertex must appear two or more times. This shows the existence of a cycle in $G$.

Determining whether a directed graph is cyclic is a decidable problem (a simple DFS visit suffices).

Comment: Thank you. Could it also be done like this please? https://ibb.co/XL3cf0P (comments are too short for full text :/)

Comment: The picture is really blurry and hard to read. Perhaps you can post the text in multiple comments or edit the question? Anyway, I don't think that approach would work. It is easy to design a PDA with $k$ states that (i) accepts a finite language, and (ii) accepts a word $w$ such that $|w| > k$. Then $L(D) \cap L(A)$ (where $D$ is a DFA that accepts words of length $ \ge k$) is non-empty and your algorithm would incorrectly accept $A$.